# Why doesn't "m of A called" get printed twice in this example?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this from https://www.python-course.eu/python3_multiple_inheritance.php:

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        print("m of A called")

class B(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of B called")
        super().m()

class C(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of C called")
        super().m()

class D(B, C):
    def m(self):
        print("m of D called")
        super().m()
```

And the output:

```
>>> from super5 import D
>>> x = D()
>>> x.m()
m of D called
m of B called
m of C called
m of A called
```

I'm a beginner at programming and I'm struggling to understand how super() and MRO works. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: Because that's what `super` is *for*, to help ensure that all of the implementations in the MRO get called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super` makes sure that you follow the method resolution order. So if every class contains a (proper) `super` it will follow the MRO of the class you originally called the method on.

In your case it's an instance of `D` and the MRO of `D` is:

```
>>> D.mro()
[D, B, C, A, object]
```

So it will first use `D.m` that calls super which goes to `B.m` which in turn calls super which is `C.m` that uses super which then calls `A.m`. However here it stops because `A` doesn't use `super` - so it won't try to call `object.m`.

Since `A` isn't present twice in the MRO (not sure if that would be possible) there's no reason to expect it to be called twice. At least not if you just use `super`s.

In case you're wondering how the MRO is created there is an [official documentation](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) for it. In short: Siblings (child classes with the same parent) are called before the parent is called, but just because a parent has multiple childs doesn't mean it is called multiple times.